# Serverless Python package- dlib dependency

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I am building a Python deployment package for AWS Lambda that relies on dlib. dlib has OS dependencies and it relies on cmake in order to build out the binaries. I am wondering how to do this given that I have a Mac and am doing my development on that environment. I am aware of Docker but I am not sure how to setup an image to compile the binaries for AWS. Any help in doing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the plugin

> serverless-package-python-functions

So simply define in the serverless.yml

```
package:
 individually: true

custom:
  pkgPyFuncs:
    buildDir: _build
    requirementsFile: requirements.txt
    cleanup: true
    useDocker: true
```

Important is to use useDocker: true - this is spinning up a docker (locally) based on the AWS AMI - therefore you get the right dependencies.

After that create your function in serverless.yml:

```
functions:
  test:
    name: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-${self:service}-test
    handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
    package:
      include:
        - ./test
      artifact: ${self:custom.pkgPyFuncs.buildDir}/${self:functions.test.name}.zip
```

Inside your test-folder place the `requirements.txt`. This file will be used for deploying the service with the right packages.

let me know if you have further questions